# Geometry problem from BMO2 2001 with angle bisector of a triangle

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I was attempting the [2001 BMO 2](https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo2-2001.pdf) and was unable to solve question 3. The question was:

> A triangle ABC has $\measuredangle ACB > \measuredangle ABC$.
> The internal bisector of $\measuredangle BAC$ meets BC at D.
> The point E on AB is such that $\measuredangle EDB = 90◦$.
> The point F on AC is such that $\measuredangle BED = \measuredangle DEF$.
> Show that $\measuredangle BAD = \measuredangle FDC$.

My progress:

I first started out labelling $\measuredangle BAD = \measuredangle DAC = \alpha$ and $\measuredangle ABC = \beta$. I then did some angle chasing but found nothing interesting like a cyclic quadrilateral or parallel lines. However, I did find that FE was perpendicular to AB. I then tried to create some cyclic quadrilaterals. I chose to look at the $\triangle EFA$ first, so I drew the perpendicular from F to AD and set its foot as X. This way we have AEXF as a cyclic quadrilateral with diameter AF. Using angles in the same segment we see $\measuredangle XFE = \measuredangle XEF = \alpha$ so XE = XF. Then I drew the line XY from X to AB such that $\measuredangle XYA = \measuredangle XAY = \alpha$ which then gives XA = XY. From there, with some angle chasing you can also find that $\triangle XEY$ is a right angled triangle and is congruent to $\triangle FXA$, also $\triangle XEF$ is similar to $\triangle XYA$.

From here I couldn't find anything useful though. How would someone continue along this path or have I missed an easier path before? I have learned a little about spiral similarity before, here, would $\triangle XAY$ and $\triangle XFE$ have spiral similarity around X of 90◦? Could that be used in any way?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why "FE was perpendicular to AB"? To me, this only occurs if $\angle BED = \angle DEF = 45^\circ$, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @CalvinLin That exactly is the case. OP has considered a special case, in which $\measuredangle ABC=45^o$.

Comment: I apologise for the mistake, I just realized but In the start of my working I ended up putting $\measuredangle DEF = \measuredangle DBE$ instead of $\measuredangle DEF = \measuredangle BED$ which is what led to my incorrect conclusion that FE is perpendicular to AB. Yeah I've just realized pretty much eveything i've got is now wrong my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's draw a line from $F$ which is parallel to $CB$, intersecting $AB$ at $G$. Since $ED$ is perpendicular to $FG$, and $\angle FED=\angle GED$, we can easily conclude that $FD=DG$.
Now, let's assume $\angle ADF=y_1$, $\angle ADG=y_2$, and $\angle FDC=\angle GDB=x.$
By the law of sine in $\triangle FCD$, we have:

$$\frac{\sin (y_1+\frac{\angle A}{2})}{\sin x}=\frac{CD}{CF},$$
and in $\triangle GDB$,

$$\frac{\sin (y_2+\frac{\angle A}{2})}{\sin x}=\frac{DB}{GB}.$$
Since $FG$ and $BC$ are parallel and $AD$ is the angle bisector, we have: $\frac{CD}{CF}=\frac{DB}{GB}$.

Therefore, $\sin (y_1+\frac{\angle A}{2})=\sin(y_2+\frac{\angle A}{2}).$ So, $y_1+y_2+\frac{\angle A}{2}+\frac{\angle A}{2}=180^{\circ}.$ Hence, $AGDF$ is cyclic.

The rest is easy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See that $D$ is the $A-$excenter of $\triangle AEF$ wherefrom $\widehat{EDF}=90^\circ-\dfrac{\widehat{BAC}}2$, i.e. $\widehat{CDF}=\dfrac{\widehat{BAC}}2$.